# Java CombinationLock Program

Tags: java, input

I'm really new to Java and I'm having issues with a program required for my Java class. I need to simulate a lock and implement methods that change combination, check the number on top etc.

Well, I think there's an issue with my `openLock()` method or `alterLockCombination()` method. My program will correctly open the lock with default combination (0,0,0) but when I try and change the combination it won't work properly and only the default combination will unlock the lock.

Where are my errors here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lock {

public static final int CLOCKWISE = 0;
public static final int COUNTER_CLOCKWISE = 1;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

private int x;
private int y;
private int z;
private boolean isLockOpen;
private int noOnTopOfKnob;

public Lock() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    this.isLockOpen = false;
    this.noOnTopOfKnob = 0;
}

public void alterLockCombinaiton(int x, int y, int z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public void turnKnob(int direction, int noToStop){
    int i = noOnTopOfKnob;
    int numbersPassed = 0;
    System.out.println("Simulating......");

    do{
        if(direction == CLOCKWISE)
            i++;
        else if(direction == COUNTER_CLOCKWISE)
            i--;
        if(i > 39)
            i = 0;
        if (i < 0)
            i=39;
        this.noOnTopOfKnob = i;

        System.out.print(noOnTopOfKnob + " ");
        numbersPassed++;

        if(numbersPassed>40 && noOnTopOfKnob==noToStop)
            break;
    }
    while(true);
    System.out.println();
}

public void closeLock() {
    System.out.println("Locked!");
    this.isLockOpen = false;
}

public boolean openLock() {
    // initializing with arbitrary values
    int firstStop = -1;
    int secondStop = -1;
    int thirdStop = -1;
    int firstRotation = -1;
    int secondRotation = -1;
    int thirdRotation = -1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a number (0-39) " + i + ": ");
        int noToStop = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter 0 for clockwise and 1 for counter-clockwise) " + i + ": ");
        int direction = in.nextInt();
        turnKnob(direction, noToStop);

        if(i == 1) {
            firstStop = noToStop;
            firstRotation = direction;

        }
        else if(i == 2) {
            secondStop = noToStop;
            secondRotation = direction;
        }
        else if(i == 3) {
            thirdStop = noToStop;
            thirdRotation = direction;
        }

        if(firstStop == this.x && firstRotation == CLOCKWISE
                && secondStop == this.y && secondRotation == COUNTER_CLOCKWISE
                && thirdStop == this.z && thirdRotation == CLOCKWISE) {

            this.isLockOpen = true;
        }

    }
    return isLockOpen;
}

public boolean isLockOpen() {
    return this.isLockOpen;
}

public int getNoAtTop() {
    return noOnTopOfKnob;
}

}
```

**END of Lock.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LockInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("\nWelcome to lock simulator");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

            menu();
 }

    public static void menu() {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            Lock newLock = new Lock();
            int xInput, yInput, zInput;

            System.out.println("\nSelect an option for the lock.\n");
            System.out.println("    A : Set a new lock combination. ");
            System.out.println("    B : Close the lock.");
            System.out.println("    C : Attempt to open the lock.");
            System.out.println("    D : Check lock status.");
            System.out.println("    E : Check current top number.");
            System.out.println("    Q : Quit program.");

            char menuOption = scnr.next().charAt(0);
            menuOption = Character.toUpperCase(menuOption);

            switch(menuOption) {
                    case 'A':
                            System.out.println("Set a new combination for the lock.\n");
                            System.out.println("Enter the first number of the combination.");
                            xInput = scnr.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the second number of the combination.");
                            yInput = scnr.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the third number of the combination.");
                            zInput = scnr.nextInt();

                            newLock.alterLockCombinaiton(xInput,yInput,zInput);
                            menu();
                            break;
                    case 'B':
                            newLock.closeLock();
                            menu();
                            break;
                    case 'C':
                            newLock.openLock();
                            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println("After lock open attemp....");
                            System.out.println("No on top: " + newLock.getNoAtTop());
                            System.out.println("Lock is open: " + newLock.isLockOpen());
                            menu();
                            break;
                    case 'D':
                            System.out.println("Lock is open: " + newLock.isLockOpen());
                            menu();
                            break;
                    }

    }
}
```

LockInput class is unfinished since I'm trying to figure out my input issue first.

Comment: Just for the record: dont use an "int" to define CLOCK/COUNTERCLOCK. It would be more appropriate to use an enum instead...

Comment: Beyond that: be more disciplined about vertical spacing: A) follow java coding standards regarding where you put braces/newlines B) be consistent: dont put new lines randomly: use them to really group things that belong together ... together. Dont just use new lines because you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a `new Lock()` each time `menu()` is called.

So, the modified combination will be immediately replaced by the default one since `menu()` gets called just after that, and the lock replaced by a new `Lock` instance :

```
newLock.alterLockCombinaiton(xInput,yInput,zInput);
menu();
```

You may want to remove `Lock newLock = new Lock();` from `menu()`, and declare it as a static variable at the class level instead :

```
static Lock newLock = new Lock();
```

Better yet, as suggested by @GhostCat to avoid the static variable :

Create the object in the `main` method

```
Lock newLock = new Lock();
```

Change the `menu()` method to `menu(Lock newLock)`

Then call it from `main` : `menu(newLock);`

The same goes for the `Scanner` variable, you'll probably figure that part out .

Comment: I would rather suggest that main() creates Scanner/Lock and **passes** those to the menu() as parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much! I created the object and scanner in main and passed them to menu() as parameters and that worked.